# Putting a duration in Login Attempt

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I have created an information about Login attempt. But I want to put an duration if attempts are gone, "Your attempt reach 0, please try again in 3 minute".

**ISSUE**

The problem in my code is, when I burned 1 attempt the message pop up. Supposedly, it will come if all attempts is gone.

## JAVA

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mobile__grocery);
    ocLogin();
}

public void ocLogin () {
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Email);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
    attempts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
    login_btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Login);
    attempts.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));

    login_btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!allowedtoLogin) {
                        Toast.makeText(Mobile_Grocery.this, "Your attempt reach 0, please wait 3 minutes to log again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    if (email.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&
                            password.getText().toString().equals("pass")) {
                        Toast.makeText(Mobile_Grocery.this, "Email and Password is correct",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.admin.mobile_grocery.Method");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {
                        allowedtoLogin = false;
                        Toast.makeText(Mobile_Grocery.this, "Email and Password is incorrect",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                allowedtoLogin = true;
                            }
                        },WAIT_TIME);


                        attempt_counter--;
                        attempts.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));
                        if (attempt_counter == 0) {
                            login_btn.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
    );

}
```

## XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".Mobile_Grocery"
android:id="@+id/mobile_grocery"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mobile_grocery_bckgrnd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/mobile_grocery"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/mobile_grocery_main"
    android:id="@+id/mobilegrocery"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Email"
    android:hint="@string/email_text"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Password"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Password"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Password" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Password"
    android:hint="@string/password_text"
    android:textColorHint="#000000"
    android:layout_marginBottom="119dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/mobilegrocery"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mobilegrocery"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
    android:password="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/Login"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Email"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Password"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Password"
    android:src="@drawable/login_button"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
    android:onClick="ocLogin"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/attempt_text"
    android:id="@+id/attleft"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:src="@drawable/register"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Login"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Login"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Login" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/register"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/register"
    android:password="false" />
```

> Everytime I clicked the Login Button with wrong credentials, attempt will reduce 1, and so on.......

Comment: duplicate of -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063251/login-attempt-with-duration

Answer (score 0):

It pops up the message in the first attempt because you are changing `allowedtoLogin` to `false` in the first attempt. I am posting your code with edits you can check that and try:

```
login_btn.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!allowedtoLogin) {
                    Toast.makeText(Mobile_Grocery.this, "Your attempt reach 0, please wait 3 minutes to log again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    if (email.getText().toString().equals("admin") &&
                        password.getText().toString().equals("pass")) {
                        Toast.makeText(Mobile_Grocery.this, "Email and Password is correct",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.admin.mobile_grocery.Method");
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {

                       Toast.makeText(Mobile_Grocery.this, "Email and Password is incorrect",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       attempt_counter--;
                       attempts.setText(Integer.toString(attempt_counter));
                       if (attempt_counter == 0) {
                         // Moved allowedLogin = false inside this if 
                           allowedtoLogin = false;
                           login_btn.setEnabled(false);
                           new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                 attempt_counter = 3;
                                 allowedtoLogin = true;
                              }
                          },WAIT_TIME);
                       }
                    }
               }

            }
        }
);
```

Comment: Sir! The output is, when I burned 3 attempts no message pop saying "Your attempt reach 0, please wait 3 minutes to log again". Just like my first code.

Comment: can you log values of `attemptCounter` on each click and whats `WAIT_TIME` value ?

Comment: private static final int WAIT_TIME = 3 * 60 * 1000;

Comment: int attempt_counter = 3 ;

Comment: debug your `attempt_counter` value in each click

Comment: yes you can do that or just do like this `Log.d("Counter Value",attempt_counter+"")` inside your `onClick()` method and check output in your `LogCat`

Comment: debugging... wait sir a little bit laggy

Comment: I dont know if I get what you mean. But there's 1 thing I found when I debugging, onClick59(),Mobile Grocery $1... When I clicked it, it drives me to attempt_counter--;